Суммирование рабочих часов для сотрудников
В гугл таблице у меня расположен график сотрудников. Каждый лист в нём, это отдельный месяц. Начиная с третьей строки, сверху вниз, перечисляются ФИО сотрудников. На против каждого расставлены нормативные часы (сколько отработал). А в последнем столбце, на против каждого сотрудника, находится значение переработанных часов. Мне необходимо суммировать каждое значение переработанных часов за каждый месяц (со всех листов), для каждого сотрудника по отдельности и если его переработка более 120, то ставить пометку "Ошибка".


К примеру, сотрудник "Котова Елена". Берём её переработки с каждого листа, суммируем и если это значение больше 120, то в последней столбик ставим пометку "Ошибка"
Буду благодарен любым вариантам.
function workHourse() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = sheet.getSheets();

for(var i = 0; i < activeSheet.length; i++) {
if(!activeSheet[i].isSheetHidden()) { 

// Все данные со всех листов
  var list = activeSheet[i];
  var data = list.getDataRange();

// Объекты со значениями / не знаю, нужны ли они вообще...?
  var user = {};
  var hourse = {};

// Диапазон переработки
  var dataRows = data.getNumRows();
  var dataColumns = data.getNumColumns();
  var lastColumnList = list.getRange(6, dataColumns - 1, dataRows);

// Диапазон сотрудников
  var userData = list.getRange('C6:C');

// ФИО сотрудников и их часы
  var valuesHourse = lastColumnList.getValues();
  var valuesUser = userData.getValues();

// Прохожу циклом по каждому сотруднику и его рабочему времени
  for(var j = 0; j < valuesHourse; j++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < valuesUser; k++) {
      // Дальше я перепробовал все, что я знаю, варианты и никак не смог добиться нужного результата
    };
   };
  };
 };
};


Добрый день, попробуйте сочетание формул QUERY и SUMIF (СУММАЕСЛИ в русском варианте)

Добрый день. К сожалению, что касается формул, я полный профан. Ещё больший, чем в скриптах. Если у вас есть небольшой пример, то я с радостью опробую. Спасибо за ответ.

для примера формулы неплохо бы было получить пример данных в виде таблицы, а не скриншота.

А чего так сложно заморачиваться и еще скрипт использовать.
По факту: Условно есть 12 страниц - это 12 таблиц на каждый месяц. ОК, здорово, все шаблонно.
Решение:  Просто сделать еще одну страницу, например отчетную (или итоговую):

На этой странице можно иметь столбик со всеми ФИО сотрудниками, которые можно автоматически переносить во все другие листы месячных таблиц.
Вторая колонка это может быть сумма переработки собранная со всех листов-таблиц простой формулой Таблицы =SUM(Январь!Z3;Февраль!Z3;....;Декабрь!Z3)
Январь!Z3 - это для примера, нужен реальный адрес ячейки.
Затем размножаете эту функцию для всех ФИО в отчетном листе - и всё.
Теперь, при каждом изменении в листах-таблицах каких-либо данных о часах - на отчетном листе все будет автоматически видно.

Это самый простейший вариант, но можно и усложнить и исользовать SUMIF, а если очень заморочиться то и QUERY, но смысла в этом не вижу.
